# Snowflake: Joining a Table with Effective Dates and older records are showing NULL

Tags: join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Summary:

In Snowflake I have a table which records the maximum number of an item which changes every so often. I want to be able to join the max number of the item for that date (effective_date). This is the most basic "example" as in my table has items "expire" when they are removed.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ITEM
(
 Item VARCHAR(10),
 Quantity Number(5,0),
 EFFECTIVE_DATE DATE
)
;

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE REPORT
(
 INVOICE_DATE DATE,
 ITEM VARCHAR(10)
)
;

INSERT INTO REPORT
VALUES
('2021-02-01', '100'),
('2021-09-10', '100')
;

INSERT INTO ITEM
VALUES
('100', '10', '2021-01-01'),
('101', '15', '2021-01-01'),
('100', '5', '2021-09-01')
;

SELECT * FROM REPORT t1
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT * FROM ITEM
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM ORDER BY EFFECTIVE_DATE desc) = 1
) t2 on t1.ITEM = t2.ITEM AND t1.INVOICE_DATE <= t2.EFFECTIVE_DATE
;
```

Returns

```
INVOICE_DATE,ITEM,ITEM,QUANTITY,EFFECTIVE_DATE
2021-02-01,100,100,5,2021-09-01
2021-09-10,100,NULL,NULL,NULL
```

How do I fix this so I no longer get NULL entries on my join.
Thank you for reading this!

I am hoping to get a result like this

```
INVOICE_DATE,ITEM,ITEM,QUANTITY,EFFECTIVE_DATE
2021-02-01,100,100,10,2021-01-01
2021-09-10,100,100,5,2021-09-01
```

Comment: There is no matching row, and that's why you get NULL from the ITEM table. Do you want to show something else instead of NULL?

Comment: Added what I would like the result to look like.

Comment: I think it is all about my join, I do not know how to get it only to use the 1 result based upon the effective date.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with your data and your expectations.  Your query is this:

```
SELECT * FROM REPORT t1
LEFT JOIN
(
SELECT * FROM ITEM
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM ORDER BY EFFECTIVE_DATE desc) = 1
) t2 on t1.ITEM = t2.ITEM AND t1.INVOICE_DATE <= t2.EFFECTIVE_DATE
;
```

which requires that the INVOICE_DATE be less than or equal to the EFFECTIVE DATE of the ITEM.  This isn't the case, though.  `2021-09-10` is greater than `2021-09-01` so you don't get a join hit, which is why you get NULLs.  It's also why your other record is returning the wrong information from your expectations.